# URLSession Error when Downloading file failed because of less memory In phone

Tags: ios, swift, urlsession

I am trying to download file from my App and I have a Question About it what happens if phone has less memory than file size that is being downloading..

Is It trigger below urlSession delegate ? If it is what is the error?

```
 public func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, 
   didCompleteWithError error: Error?) {
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [NSURLSessionDownloadTask issues with Storage almost full disk warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36133758/nsurlsessiondownloadtask-issues-with-storage-almost-full-disk-warnings) and https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/43263 it would seem that you will get an error and its domain will be `NSPOSIXErrorDomain` with an error code of `ENOSPC` (Error, No Space).

There is also the possibility of getting an error with the domain of `NSCocoaErrorDomain` and an error code of `NSFileWriteOutOfSpaceError`.

```
public func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask,  didCompleteWithError error: Error?) {
    if let nserror = error as? NSError {
        if (nserror.domain == NSPOSIXErrorDomain && nserror.code == ENOSPC) ||
           (nserror.domain == NSCocoaErrorDomain && nserror.code == NSFileWriteOutOfSpaceError) {
            // Not enough space
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am passing (error?.localizedDescription)! to Alert .. So what ever error comes it will show on Alert right ..?

Comment: Yes, if you want to show the error to a user, using `localizedDescription` is what you need. But properly unwrap the optional. Don't use `!`.